# ng-grid control and row without cells?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid and would like to omit cells in some of the rows, creating table `colspan` effect.I tried with simply not defining those cells, however they end up empty in the grid, and the border is visible.Is it actually possible to create `colspan` effect with ng-grid? So that border is not visible for not defined cells ?